# cordova camera plugin - How to set screen crop?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to implement an apache cordova mobile app which takes pictures and retrieve them from gallery. The problem is I do **NOT** want to take whole screen pictures. I need to **crop** the screen ***while taking the picture*** somehow like in the example picture below. Is there a way to implement this? By the way I am using VS 2015 and apache cordova camera plugin istalled.

Thanks in advance & Best Regards.

PS: I will share an image in order to describe what I want.

EdiT 1: [camera crop sample](http://pasteboard.co/185ZC1No.png)

EdiT 2: Actually it is OK to **crop after taking the image**. I think there is a crop plugin to do this.

Comment: It's not possible with the camera plugin, the camera plugin allow you to crop after taking the picture, if you want to crop it while taking the picture you will have to create your own plugin

Comment: @jcesarmobile very bad news my friend :) How to create plugins by the way?

Comment: I will try to use this plugin [link]https://github.com/alexk111/ngImgCrop

Comment: that's for cropping images after taking them, not from the camera. If you want to crop from the camera, you have to create a native plugin. See the guide http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html

Comment: I didn't see your edit 2. If it's ok to crop after taking, you can use the allowEdit option, that will display a cropping native screen after taking the photo, or you can try the plugin you mention or do your own crop with canvas